# afterLabelTextTpl usage in extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I need to display an image after a field label.
I am trying to see if I can use afterLabelTextTpl. But didnt find an example online
as how to use it.

Here is an idea of what I am trying to do. Can someone correct me syntatically..

```
                                {
                                    xtype: 'combobox',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Role',
                                    editable:false,
                                    store: roles_store, 
                                    triggerAction:'all',
                                    name: 'role_id',
                                    valueField: 'role_id',
                                    displayField:'role_name',
                                    afterLabelTextTpl : function() {

                                        {
                                            xtype: 'image',
                                            src:'../www/css/slate/btn/question.png',
                                            padding: '5 0 0 0',
                                            cls:'pointer',
                                            listeners: {
                                                el:{
                                                    click: function() {
                                                        Ext.create('Ext.tip.Tip', {
                                                            closable:true,
                                                            padding: '0 0 0 0',
                                                            maxWidth:300,
                                                            html: "<b>read-only</b>: Has read access to all pages, but can make no changes.<br><br><b>user</b>: Can edit rules and commit to production.<br><br><b>admin</b>: Can edit rules, commit to production, and add/delete users.<br><br> "+supertext
                                                        }).showAt([810, 340]);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }


                                        }
                                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `afterLabelTextTpl` is a template config, meaning that it takes either a string, an array of strings, or an instance of `Ext.XTemplate` and uses that to generate HTML.

There's no built-in way of creating a component via XTemplate (although a forum member created an extension called [CTemplate](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?148066) that allows this). So if you want to go pure Ext JS, you're going to do a little more work.

**NOTE:** I don't have access to Ext JS 4.1.3 so what follows is an approximation, based on my experience with 4.1.0. You may need to tweak the code to get it just right, but it should provide a sufficient starting point.

Step 1: Setting up your afterLabelTextTpl. Try something like this:

```
afterLabelTextTpl:'<img id="combo_icon" style="padding-top:5px" class="pointer" src="../www/css/slate/btn/question.png"/>'
```

That should get your icon showing.

Step 2: Adding the click listener. There are two ways to go about this. Both methods assume you have a function called `My.Name.Space.onImageClick`. Obviously you can replace this name with whatever you want. Here's the function:

```
My.Name.Space.onImageClick = function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.tip.Tip', {
        closable: true,
        padding:  0,
        maxWidth: 300,
        html:     '<b>whatever you want here</b>'
    }).showAt([810, 340]);
};
```

One method is to add the listener directly to the DOM.

```
'<img onclick="My.Name.Space.onImageClick();" /* the rest of the HTML here */ />'
```

The other method is to add the listener via `Ext.dom.Element` which is probably the better choice. You would need something like this in your combobox config:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(me){
        var imgEl = Ext.get("combo_icon");
        if(imgEl){
            imgEl.on("click", My.Name.Space.onImageClick);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're having specific trouble getting this working, leave a comment and I'll help clarify what I can.

Answer (score 1):

Its an XTemplate instance or a string.

From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-afterLabelTextTpl):

> An optional string or XTemplate configuration to insert
>   in the field markup after the label text. If an XTemplate is used, the
>   component's render data serves as the context.

So a string "Hello" will do, or anything that [XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) will take